# Is there a way to forcibly kill a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

In my program, I have a thread that continuosly listens to a **UDP** socket and if it gets any message, puts it in a queue.
Other threads basically do the main part of the program.
So when I want to terminate the program neatly. So I want a way to either kill the thread forcibly (but neatly) or to come out of `recv()` of the socket at regular intervals so that I can check some state variables and quit if I need to.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I regularly use:

```
import threading


class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stopper = threading.Event()
    
    def stop(self):
        self._stopper.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stopper.isSet()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped():
          """
          The Code executed by your Thread comes here.
          Keep in mind that you have to use recv() in a non- blocking manner
          """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = CustomThread()
    t.start()
    # ...
    t.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcefully killing threads is generally bad practice and should be avoided whenever possible.

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

> Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such
> as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released
> properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them
> non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.

Based on this information, I would recommend closing the thread using an Event. There is a really good example of this here: [Is there any way to kill a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread)