Kubernetes API silently hanging, causing thread leaks
I have a health monitoring script to check logs of a container every 30 seconds. The script is based on kubernetes client API, the code is pretty straight forward as below
from kubernetes import client, config, utils, watch

api_instance = client.CoreV1Api(self.k8s_client)
w = watch.Watch()
for e in w.stream(api_instance.read_namespaced_pod_log, name=pod_id,
     namespace=namespace, tail_lines=lines, container=container):
         blah...

I run this inside a thread and keep checking thread.is_alive() to ensure my thread is running.
Recently, I started logging the number of threads actively running in my application, which was drastically higher than expected.
It turns out that the API hangs, thread.is_alive() is false, and I will create a new thread.
However, the old thread is active, running and hanging.
Is this a known Kubernetes issue? Is there any other way I could deal with this forever-hanging thread?

Can you share how you can tell the thread is hanging?  Is  it coming from a thread generated in your python code?

@Rico thread.is_alive() check fails and if I do thread.join(), my application will pause forever. If I run, threads.enumerate(), I can see the crashed thread shows up as an active running Python thread. Based on that, I concluded that the thread is hanging.

have you tried any one of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69092420/is-there-a-way-to-forcibly-kill-a-thread-in-python ?

@Rico yes, already tried this. somehow doesn't reach the check, gets lost in w.stream()
